# SQL 2008 R2 User Connections and Total Server Memory counters spike at the same time on multiple servers

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server-2008, monitoring, sql

We use SolarWinds SAM software to monitor servers and applications. We started using it to monitor our SQL servers through the performance counters.

We started getting alerts two to three times daily saying that the "Total Server Memory" and "User Connections" counters were too high. We get these alerts at the same time for all three servers...almost like it's synchronized to go off at the same time. The alerts reset maybe 3 minutes after going off.

I haven't been able to find any reason why this is happening. Any idea what may be causing this, or how to track down the cause?

The queries used to pull the data are as follows.

For "User Connections":

```
SELECT 
    cntr_value 
FROM 
    sys.dm_os_performance_counters
WHERE 
    object_name LIKE '%:General Statistics%' AND 
    counter_name = 'User Connections'
```

For "Total Server Memory":

```
SELECT 
    cntr_value
FROM
    sys.dm_os_performance_counters
WHERE 
    object_name LIKE '%:Memory Manager%' AND 
    counter_name = 'Total Server Memory (KB)'
```

Answer (score 0):

If these alerts occur at the same time or same interval everyday they could indicate a scheduled or routine job that runs against these servers. It could be something configured on the SQL Server itself or it could be a 3rd party. It could even be a backup software backing up the databases, although I don't think a backup software would start that many connections to the server.

You should examine both the System and Application logs on the SQL boxes around the times you get these spikes. They could give you some leads on what process/application/server is creating these connections.